# NSNotificationCenter has a maximum speed?

Tags: objective-c

Using NSNotificationCenter , it worked well till i have started to send very fast messages to other class.

What is fast ? its about 30-40 notifications in second. and i dont get even 1 of them .
is there other way to do that ?
should i update a global instead ?

```
//post data out .
 - (void)post:(NSString*)string
 {
     NSLog(@"done"); //the log is printing 
     NSDictionary *userInfo = nil;
     [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"connector"
                                                         object:string
                                                       userInfo:userInfo];
 }
```

I know the observer is good cause same code worked before .
Thanks a lot .

Comment: what is the point of to use the notification center for a direct one-to-one communication between _two_ classes...?

Comment: At the risk of starting a war, the OP is asking about using `NSNotificationCenter`. Whether or not that is good idea (as pointed out by @holex) is a [different issue](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=When+to+use+NSNotificationCenter).

Comment: @MikeD, without starting any war, there must be a quite explicit reason to request that, because we all know that the notification centre is not designed for such kind of stress basically. that is why I asked about the point...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you setting the wrong `object`, Which should be the object that posts the notification (or `nil`). What I think you should be doing adding the `string` to `userInfo`:

```
NSDictionary *userInfo = @{@"somekey" : string };
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"connector"
                                                     object:self
                                                   userInfo:userInfo];
```

Comment: sh*t ! you right :) but how is that it worked till now ? this code was copy past from other condition , that is working great, and now only after i change what you said-it do work ..

Answer (score 3):

If you're sending 30-40 notifications a second you should really think about your implementation again.

Heres some alternatives:

1. [Creating your own delegates for callbacks](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Delegation.html)
2. [Using a block](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithBlocks/WorkingwithBlocks.html)

The problem with NSNotificationCentre is that it sends the message to every observer - this can get slow and is generally used for updating views on state change (Login/Logout).